# When to close Oracle database connection at nodejs?

Tags: node.js, express, database-connection, node-oracledb

I'm using a Nodejs app to connect a +20K users of a mobile app to an Oracle database. I establish a pool of 16 connections at process startup and destroy them at process termination.

To be efficient, I provide a connection to the database for each request in an express middleware.

```
app.use(async function (req, res, next) {

try {
req.db = await oracledb.getConnection({
  poolAlias: config.DbPoolAlias,
});

res.on("finish", async () => {
  if (req.db) {
    await req.db.close();
  }
});

res.on("close", async () => {
  if (req.db) {
    await req.db.close();
  }
});
} catch (e) {
   next(e);
 }

   next();
});
```

This connection will be used to execute many SQL statements of a single request.

My problem is that I do not know the best or *correct* way to close the connection and return it back to the connection pool.

Following [Nodejs docs](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse), there are the *finish* and *close* events, which event to use to close the connection? I know it is wrong to use both since the node-oracledb driver does not provide isClosed or isOpened properties on the connection object to use it to use both events to be 100% sure the connection is closed.

My top priority is to be sure that the connection is closed no matter what happens. I'm open to solutions other than the response object events.

Comment: Why don't you call `req.db.close()` in the controller once you get the results from the db? I mean `const result = req.db.execute(...); req.db.close();`. This would be the fastest way to release the connection back to the pool.

Comment: Because then I have to do it at the end of each request handler. I do not want to do this.

Comment: You can add a wrapper for `res.json` function like for example `res._json = res.json;  res.json = function(data){ this.req.db.close(); this._json(data); }` or add it directly to http.ServerResponse.prototype. It's just an idea not a recommendation though.

Comment: The interesting bit of the problem is how & when you are executing SQL statements.  Are these pre-determined in some way?  Can you wrap that sequence of calls with the connection/close calls? Make sure to close the connection in any error paths.  Use the node-oracledb pool stats to check the pool queue behavior and see if you are leaking (not closing) connections.

Comment: @ChristopherJones, It something like this https://pastebin.com/NVannaHt.

I'm trying to close the connection in a centralized location to avoid missing the closing somewhere.

Comment: Put a try/catch around the two execute() calls.  Get a connection from the pool at the top and then do the close() in a finally block.  Then do the send.  Do you really need that commit call? Your PL/SQL function names don't indicate they change data? The call is an extra round-trip so it has an impact on ultimate app scalability.   You might get some tips from the way routing is handled in https://github.com/oracle/oracle-db-examples/tree/master/javascript/rest-api  PS it's would be better for the Stackoverflow community to update your question with that code instead of using pastebin.

Comment: "Put a try/catch around the two execute() calls. Get a connection from the pool at the top and then do the close() in a finally block."

This is the standard procedure of any database driver. First, it is not what I seek, and second, I come from Microsoft's Entity Framework and IBM's Integration Bus background in which database connection opening/closing are managed by the framework since they are a must-do operations to interact with any database.

Comment: I chose res.on("finish") and load tested the API using 6 parallel sessions, each with a 1000 different successful/fail calls. The connections were closed each time.

Comment: I will remove unnecessary commits or set autoCommit in the last call as described in the docs.